# What is the best way to implement Dark mode in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add dark mode in my React Native App. I have come across many implementations including React Navigation and Appearance. Everywhere I see code similar to the one below:-

```
import { Text, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
const theme = useColorScheme();

<Text style={theme === 'light' ? styles.text_light : styles.text_dark}>Hello</Text>
```

But using these ternary operators everywhere is adding up to noise in code. I have created my custom Text and View as you can see below.

```
  import { Text, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
  const theme = useColorScheme();

  const CustomText = ({ styles, children }) => {
    return (
      <Text
        style={[
          theme === 'dark' ? { color: 'white' } : { color: 'black' },
          styles,
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    );
  };
```

My Question is, Is my solution feasible? Can I replace React Native Components like Text and View(that get used everywhere) with custom components, or the ternary operator in React Components a better way. Thank you.

Comment: you can use styled-components, it is very useful, please check documentation for details https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

Comment: [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html) is an excellent library for theming. It comes with a default light and dark scheme, and allows for customization of those schemes

Comment: Thank for you answer, I will implement react-native-paper. But can you tell me Using my custom components in place of View and Text is going to have any impact on my app? @PhantomSpooks

Answer (score 0):

react-native-paper provides components that are colored using the theme stored in the PaperProvider context. React navigation has a similar context. Since these themes are compatible with one another, here's an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/7BYoFNmSa) where users allow to manipulate                                                                                                                                                                                both:

First merge the paper and navigation light and dark schemes:

```js
// React native paper theme is compatible with react-navigation theme
// so merge them
const CombinedDefaultTheme = merge(
  PaperDefaultTheme,
  NavigationDefaultTheme
);
const CombinedDarkTheme = merge(PaperDarkTheme, NavigationDarkTheme);
```

Now I create a function that will customize the merged scheme base on a provided color and whether or not dark mode is desired:

```js
// create theme base on provided color  and whether in darkmode
export const getTheme = (color, isDarkMode) => {
  // use color scheme generator to get colors
  const [primary, accent, ...otherColors] =
    colorSchemes.getNeutralScheme(color);
  const colorPresets = isDarkMode
    ? darkenColorPresets
    : lightenColorPresets;
  // get lighter and darker versions of these colors
  const primaryPresets = colorPresets(primary);
  const accentPresets = colorPresets(accent);
  // get default paper& navigation theme
  const DefaultTheme = isDarkMode
    ? CombinedDarkTheme
    : CombinedDefaultTheme;
  //override theme with changes
  const theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      primary,
      accent,
      primaryPresets,
      accentPresets,
      otherColors,
    },
  };
  // make background color darker
  const onDark = {
    background: colorManipulators.blend(primary, "#000", 0.8),
  };
  // make text lighter version of background color
  onDark.text = colorManipulators.blend(onDark.background, "#fff", 0.6);
  if (isDarkMode) theme.colors = { ...theme.colors, ...onDark };
  return theme;
};
```

And now put this theme into a piece of state with `useReducer`:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { getTheme } from "../colors";
const initialState = {
  mainColor: "#0D3FF8",
};
initialState.isDarkMode = false;
initialState.theme = getTheme(
  initialState.mainColor,
  initialState.isDarkMode
);

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "setMainColor": {
      let newColor = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        mainColor: newColor,
        theme: getTheme(newColor, state.isDarkMode),
      };
    }
    case "overrideTheme": {
      let newTheme = action.payload;
      return { ...state, theme: { ...state.theme, ...newTheme } };
    }
    case "setIsDark": {
      const newDark = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        isDarkMode: newDark,
        theme: getTheme(state.mainColor, newDark),
      };
    }
  }
};

export default function ThemeReducer(stateOverride = {}) {
  console.log("here is the state override");
  console.log(stateOverride);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    ...initialState,
    isDarkMode: useColorScheme() == "dark",
    ...stateOverride,
  });
  return { ...state, dispatch };
}
```

Comment: if u want to use the react-native-paper theme outside a RNP component then you can access the them with the `useTheme` hook